# How to access checked property of a material UI <Checkbox/> and set it equal to false when pressing another icon (delete icon)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, material-ui, components

I hope you are all doing great! I have a question and it would be amazing if someone could give me some information or direction on how to tackle my problem.

My problem is how to access the checked property of a material-ui `<Checkbox checked={}/>` component and set it equal to false or in other words, toggle it off when pressing a button. My problem is that the delete icon (button) exists in another file which means it is a different component. Furthermore, the button's `onClick={}` event has a property **onClearSelected** which is responsible of erasing strings inside looking like cells.

Further, I hope that I gave you some insight and I did not confuse you further. I would be glad to answer to any questions and I am sorry in advance if it is hard for you to understand what I am trying to imply.

Sincerely,
Nikolaos

Comment: You do not change elements directly. With React you create a state variable which you then use in your JSX. As in `<Checkbox checked={someStateVariable} />`. Now you can simply set the state variable to a new value to change the checkbox. If the delete button is in another file you probably also need this: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: @ChrisG Yea I have already tried the first part. However, the link seems that could do the trick. Thank you mate! I will try this tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate checkbox you can simply use a ref, see useRef() in React docs.

To make a component alter something in a different component by a button click, you need to declare the ref in their common parent, then pass the ref to checkbox, either with prop drilling or a context.

Also in the parent component, create a function that unchecks the checkbox. Pass it down to the button, again with either prop drilling or with a context.